# Amazon server IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, server, amazon-cloudfront

The json for the ips is found at https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

However the only ranges for 54.233 are:

54.233.0.0/ 18
54.233.64.0 / 18
54.233.128.0 / 17

It is my understanding that 54.233.0.0 / 18 means the range is 54.233.0.0 - 54.233.0.18

Yet, 54.233.86.245 is an amazon server according to who.is but is not in any of the ranges in the json.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something or is the list provided incorrect?

Comment: `It is my understanding that 54.233.0.0 / 18 means the range is 54.233.0.0 - 54.233.0.18` No, the /18 is the subnet mask https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Comment: Thanks, im just an analyst and apparently the data architect I asked didnt know what he was talking about. Embarrassing haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. That's not how subnets work.

As pointed by Paul in comments:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Online calculator:
http://jodies.de/ipcalc

So basically, an example: 54.233.0.0/18

http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=54.233.0.0&mask1=18&mask2=

**54.233.0.0/18** = all IPs between **54.233.0.1** and **54.233.63.254**

If instead of having a CIDR you have the the size of the subnet, you can get the CIDR by doing the following:
64.233.160.0 w/ a subnet size of 8192 <=> 64.233.160.0/(**32-log2(8192)**) <=> **64.233.160.0/19**

You can also see subnets being written as **54.233.0.0/255.255.192.0** for example. The 2nd part is the actually mask, so if you transform to binary it's actually 255.255.192.0 <=> 11111111 11111111 11000000 00000000 which in turn is 18 ones so /18. The ones in the mask are the bits that are fixed when this mask is applied over the base address (54.233.0.0 in this case). Also as a side effect the base last 32-18 bits are going to be 0.

Comment: The list I have for google servers is:

64.233.160.0 / 8192
66.102.0.0 / 4096
66.249.64.0 / 8192
72.14.192.0 / 16384
74.125.0.0 / 65536
209.85.128.0 / 32768
216.239.32.0 / 8192

Those numbers after seem wayyyyy to big?

Comment: that's roughly the same thing. Instead of having the size of the mask in bits you have the size of the subnet (in the calculator that was linked above it's shown as Host/Net (it's actually that number + 2). to get the number you do /19 => 2^(32-19) = 8192 so 64.233.160.0 / 8192 is eq w/ 64.233.160.0/19. The other way around you do 16834 => 32 - log2(16834) = 32-16 = /16 so 74.125.0.0 / 65536 is eq w/ 74.125.0.0 / 16